# EnumMap constructor not found

Tags: java, enums, enum-map

Given that I have the requisite

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.EnumMap;
```

and

```
enum Terrain { ... }
```

then as far as I can tell from the documentation, this should work

```
static EnumMap<Terrain, Color> colors = new EnumMap<Terrain, Color>(Terrain.class);
```

but it actually gives me this error

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor EnumMap()
location: class java.util.EnumMap<Terrain,java.awt.Color>
static EnumMap<Terrain,Color>colors=new EnumMap<Terrain, Color>();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code the compiler is quoting doesn't match what you've claimed to have. It looks like you're not *actually* providing an argument to the constructor. This works fine, for example:

```
import java.util.EnumMap;

enum Foo {}

public class Test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnumMap<Foo, String> map = new EnumMap<Foo, String>(Foo.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, you're right, what actually happened was Netbeans (6.9) had started failing to recognize the source file as modified and therefore failing to save it even when explicitly directed to do so. No idea why Netbeans glitched like that, but copy pasting to UltraEdit and saving from there, solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error shows an no-arg constructor.

Are you sure you're looking at the right code/ have recompiled it?